# Simple modules over formal power series in one variable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> What are the simple finite dimensional modules over $k[[x]]$ (the ring of formal power series over a field $k$)?

Since $k[[x]]$ is a principal ideal domain, such modules much be torsion, but i can't figure out anything more. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M$ be a simple module over $k[[x]]$. Let $m\in M$, $m\neq 0$ be arbitrary. Then $k[[x]]\rightarrow M$, $f(x)\mapsto f(x).m$ is surjective, since $M$ is simple and the image is a non-zero submodule. Denote the kernel by $I$, so that we have an isomorphism $k[[x]]/I\cong M$ of $k[[x]]$-modules. Since $M$ is simple, so is $k[[x]]/I$, whose submodules correspond to submodules of $k[[x]]$ containing $I$. This shows that $I$ is a maximal submodule/ideal of $k[[x]]$.
As $k[[x]]$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $(x)$, it follows that $I = (x)$ and hence $M = k[[x]]/(x) = k$. Therefore, $k$ is the only simple $k[[x]]$-module, where $x$ acts by zero.

Note that this argument is valid for any field $k$.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, you might consider upvoting and (if this is the best answer) accepting it. In this way, you can give credit for the effort spent to answer your question.